# Equivalent definition of closed convex hull in real normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

> Let $X$ be a real normed space and $A \subset X$ a nonempty subset. We define the closed convex hull of $A$ to be the subset
> $$\overline{\text{conv}}(A):=\bigcap \{B\subset X:A\subset B, B \text{ is closed and convex}\}.$$
> $\overline{\text{conv}}(A)$ is a closed convex subset of $X$ with the property that if $C \subset X$ is closed and convex, and $A \subset C$, then $\overline{\text{conv}}(A) \subset C$.

Show that
$$\overline{\text{conv}}(A) = \{x \in X : \text{ for all } f \in X', f(x) \leq \sup_{a\in A} f(a)\},$$
where $X'$ is the dual of $X$.

I first tried proving that this set in convex, which was pretty straightforward. 
Let $x,y\in \overline{\text{conv}}(A)$, then for $t\in [0,1]$ we have that $tx+(1-t)y\in X$. 
In particular for all $f\in X'$ we have that $f(tx+(1-t)y)=tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)\leq t\sup_{a\in A}f(a)+(1-t)\sup_{a\in A}f(a)=\sup_{a\in A}f(a)$. 
Thus $tx+(1-t)y\in \overline{\text{conv}}(A)$. 
Showing that the set is closed is shown in the comments.

Lastly I'm really lost on how to prove the last property, that is: if $C \subset X$ is closed and convex, and $A \subset C$, then $\overline{\text{conv}}(A) \subset C$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that you mean this for the actual definition the convex hull. But I mean to prove the second definition, that is the one that uses the sup.

Comment: $\{x \in X : f(x) \leq \sup_{a\in A} f(a)\}$  is closed by continuity of $f$. Take intersection over $f$.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for proving that it's closed. Any tips for showing the last property?

Comment: You need to use a separation theorem.